# The 'imagen' attribute has no file associated with it. DJANGO

Tags: html, python, django

Tengo un problema con Django, cargando una imagen desde el models o data base, cuando escribo para ser llamada me sale ese problema.
HTML:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así esta en el HTML para que aparezca en pantalla.

models:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi esta el models.

Views:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me ayudaría mucho si alguien me ayudara ver el problema, llevo buscando un montón de tiempo y nada que encuentro la solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que tu error está en lo siguiente:

Estas colocando `{{x.imagen.url}}` en el **src** del img.
Y ese atributo no existe en la base de datos.

Lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:
Colocar un **static** y luego el **x.imagen** sin **.url**

EJEMPLO:

```
<img src="{% static '{{x.imagen}}'%}">
```

Ya que esto devolvera lo siguiente al HTML: `<img src="static/imagen_url.png">` Osea devolvera la ruta real del archivo.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias amigo, Tenias razón el atributo no estaba en la base de datos, mil gracias por tomarte tu tiempo, fue un despiste mío